# Python script waits external command to be finished before continuing

Tags: python, windows, command, external

I have a very simple Python script which parse somme data and write the output in a text file.

```
with open(debug, 'w') as debugFile:
 debugFile.write(metreDebug)
```

At the end of the script I want to open this text file so that the user can directly see the output.

```
osCommandString = "notepad.exe " + debug
os.system(osCommandString)
```

Yes... this is a developpement on windows.
Unfortunately, the python script waits that user close the notepad before continuing.

Any ideas on how to fix that issue?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you really want to use `os.system`, you have to use `start notepad.exe`. But you really shouldn’t use `os.system`, as its own docs explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Subprocess module instead.

```
import subprocess
with open(debug, 'w') as debugFile:
 debugFile.write(metreDebug)

osCommandString = "notepad.exe " + debug
subprocess.Popen(osCommandString)
```

You can read more about it here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks !
I was using

```
subprocess.call(osCommandString)
```